# Split code from result side by side in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Does anyone know if it's possible to work like this in sqldeveloper?

[image]

I want to write the code in the left side and display the result in the right side, i tried to split the window, but it splits two different worksheets. I apologize for the bad drawing example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not supported.

Code up top, result down below.

Comment: It's an existing ER, it's just also that the current framework we use makes this VERY hard to implement.